# ZK code returning org.zkoss.zk.ui.UiException and java.lang.NumberFormatException?

Tags: java, exception, zk, numberformatexception, zul

I receive the following exceptions `org.zkoss.zk.ui.UiException` and `java.lang.NumberFormatException`. Can someone please help? My stacktrace is as follows:

```
Nov 08, 2013 10:43:17 AM org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.UiEngineImpl handleError:1359
SEVERE: >>org.zkoss.zk.ui.UiException: For input string: "Enter Number"
>>java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "Enter Number"
>>  at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(Unknown Source)
>>  at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Unknown Source)
>>  at com.abcd.acd.a.web.viewmodel.FolderInfoEditViewModel.loadFolderInfoList(FolderInfoEditViewModel.java:633)
>>  at com.abcd.acd.a.web.viewmodel.FolderInfoEditViewModel.afterCompose(FolderInfoEditViewModel.java:116)
>>  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
```

My Zul file:

```xml
<zk if="${civilInfoData.infoType.equalsIgnoreCase('n') and !civilInfoData.encrypted }">
       <doublebox value="@bind(civilInfoData.folderInforecord.infoValueNumeric)" 
           hflex="1" placeholder="@load(vm.getText('FolderInfoDetail:LABEL_VALUE'))"
           mandatory="@load(civilInfoData.folderInforecord.valueRequired)"
           maxlength="10" 
           tooltiptext="@load(vm.getText('FolderInfoDetail:ENTER_NUMBER'))">
        </doublebox>
</zk>
```

Viewmodel (FolderInfoEditViewModel.java):

```java
 if (info.getInfoType().equalsIgnoreCase("n")) {
       if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(info.getFolderInforecord().getInfoValue()) &&
           !info.getFolderInforecord().getInfoValue().equalsIgnoreCase("null")) {

                     info.setInfoNumericValue(Double.parseDouble(
                                                 info.getFolderInforecord()
                                                     .getInfoValue()));

        }
  }
```

Can someone tell me how can resolve this issue?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`info.getFolderInforecord().getInfoValue()` is returning a `String` that does not successfully parse to a `double`, which is why you're getting a `NumberFormatException`.  Without more information, that's all I can say.

You're only checking that's it's not blank and not equal to "null".  You can stop your program from crashing by wrapping the code in a `try/catch` where you handle the `NumberFormatException`

Comment: THANKS  for suggestion actually i get wrong data from db this give exception.i resolve this issue delete wrong data from db.